# VBScript to Python snippet conversion

Tags: python, com, vbscript

I'm trying to convert this **VBScript** code to **Python** (Win32) code but with no luck!

```vb
Dim objMain, objSysInf, stMsg

Set objMain = CreateObject("nnetcom.oMain")

Call objMain.UnlockComponent("xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xx")

Set objSysInf = CreateObject("nnetcom.oSystemInfo")

Call objSysInf.GetSystemInfos

stMsg = objSysInf.cOsName & " " & objSysInf.cOsType & vbCrLf & _
        objSysInf.cOsCpu & vbCrLf & objSysInf.cOsMem & vbCrLf & _
        objSysInf.cOsGpu

MsgBox stMsg, vbInformation, "System Information"

Set objSysInf = Nothing
Set objMain = Nothing
```

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit with **Python 2.7.3** and **Python for Windows Extensions** installed.
Also I added COM object by executing **"makepy.pyc"** from ...**"Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\"** and with no luck, always getting some error message...

Here is my Python code:

```py
import pythoncom
import win32com.client

objMain = win32com.client.Dispach("nnetcom.oMain")

ret = objMain.UnlockComponent("xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xx")

objSysInf = win32com.client.Dispach("nnetcom.oSystemInfo")

objSysInf.GetSystemInfos()

stMsg = objSysInf.cOsName

print(stMsg)
```

Is there anybody who can help me with this conversation?

Comment: Please show full error output.

Comment: **Hi Marcin**

Here is the error output:

C:\>c:\Progra~1\Python\python.exe c:\example2.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\example2.py", line 4, in <module>
    objMain = win32com.client.Dispach("nnetcom.oMain")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Dispach'

Can you help me out?

**Ragards, Viktor**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dispach` should probably be `Dispatch`.

Comment: Ohh my God, what a Typo I made there!!! :D
Its working now, but how to make line breaks and new lines like in my VBScript code posted above? Thanks for helping me out! ;)

Comment: You can use the methods of the built-in str type, as well as the common sequence operations to split a string into the required lines. See §5.6 of the documentation of the Python standard library. Put those lines in a list. Then use `'\n'.join()` (maybe use `'\r\n'.join()` on Windows) to make a new string that contains the strings from the list, separated by newlines.

Comment: By line breaks and new lines I meant, how to write shorter line of code like in my VBScript example, see: stMsg =

Comment: You can use the `format` method of the `str` object, or concatenate strings using the `+` operator.

Comment: Yes, but how to split long code line into several code lines?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Simple explanation: If I have 1 line of code witch is 1 meter long, how to split it into 2 lines? Like in VB using & _ or + _ to split long lines.

Comment: Ah. Use the `textwrap` module. (see §7.7 of the Python standard library docs)